# Illustrator Adding Weird Lines to Logo on Dark Backgrounds (Not Stroke)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector

I have a logo symbol that has several intersecting lines. In Adobe Illustrator (CS6), slight gray lines are being added at the intersection points.

I haven't noticed it in other artwork, it only seems to appear on black (dark) backgrounds. There is no stroke.

Any idea what this is?

[image]

Comment: Is this a screenshot of Illustrator or an exported file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To me it looks like you have "Divided" the shapes with pathfinder and you need to "Unite" them with pathfinder again (the top left icon in the pathfinder window). Ctrl-Click the shapes with the same colour (or go to select > same > fill & stroke) and click "Unite" in the pathfinder window.

(If you can't see the pathfinder window go to window > Pathfinder)

Comment: That was it! Thanks so much, would have never figured that out.

Comment: You don't really *need* to re-unite the shapes except for your own reassurance: these lines are just artefacts in Illustrator's preview and will not show up in any export. They might show up in a *.pdf, but will not show when that *.pdf is printed.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking of adding that fact - I should have really haha.